# Karate test failing with 'ReferenceError: "id" is not defined' and 'no step-definition method match found for: def url apiUrl

Tags: maven, testing, karate

I am encountering a problem while running my Karate tests using Maven. The tests are failing with the following error messages:

> 1. ReferenceError: "id" is not defined
>
> - program(Unnamed:1) classpath:examples/todos/todos.feature:17
>
> 2. no step-definition method match found for: def url apiUrl
>
> - classpath:examples/todos/updateTodos.feature:4

To run my tests I'm using mvn `clean test` in my Karate project directory.
I expect all the Karate tests to pass without any errors.

Additional Context:

I am using Karate version 1.4.1.
My project structure follows the standard Maven directory layout.
The tests were working fine previously, but I started encountering these errors after some recent changes to the codebase.

The contents of my pom.xml file are as follows:

4.0.0

```
<groupId>io.karatelabs</groupId>
<artifactId>karate-template</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.11.0</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0</maven.surefire.version>        
    <karate.version>1.4.1</karate.version>
</properties>    

<dependencies>         
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>

<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>          
    </plugins>        
</build>
```

I have two feature files for testing and the contents of these files are as follows:

> todos.feature

```
Feature: Karate Basic Todos

Background:
    * url apiUrl


Scenario: Get all todos
    Given url 'http://localhost:8080/api/todos'
    When method Get
    Then status 200

Scenario: Basic todo flow

    * def taskName = "MyFirstTask"

    # Get a single todo
    Given path id 
    When method Get
    Then status 200
    And match response == { id: '#(id)', title: '#(taskName)', complete: false }

    # Create a second todo
    * def todo =
    """
        {
            "title": 'Second',
            "complete": false
        }
    """

    Given request todo 
    And header Content-Type = "application/json"
    When method Post 
    Then status 200
    And match response.title == 'Second'

    # Get all todos
    When method Get
    Then status 200
    * def firstTask = response[0]
    * match firstTask.title == taskName
    * match firstTask.complete == false


    # Clear all tasks
    Given url 'http://localhost:8080/api/reset'
    When method Get
    Then status 200
    And match response == { deleted : '#number'}
```

> updateTodos.feature

```
Feature: Second Feature File for todos

Background: 
    * url apiUrl

Scenario: Update and delete todos

    * def taskName = "MyFirstTask"

    #Create a single todo
    Given request { title: '#(taskName)', complete: false }
    When method Post
    Then status 200
    And match response == { id: '#string', title: '#(taskName)', complete: false }
    * def id = response.id

    # Update a todo
    Given path id
    And request { title: '#(taskName)', complete: true }
    When method Put 
    Then status 200
    And match response.complete == true
        
    # Delete todo
    Given path id
    When method delete
    Then status 200
```

In my karate-config.js file, I have defined the apiUrl as follows:

> apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/api/todos'

What could be causing these errors, and how can I resolve them?

Comment: I think the only way forward is for you to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue